# Android - Null pointer execute() & DialogProgress AsyncTask

Tags: android-looper

I have this code below that basically is the Login process of my app, Why do i have null pointers? Have I implemented it correctly, I have tried to use static for AsyncTask to avoid any memoryleak.

Login.java

```
    if (handler.executeLog(username.trim(), password.trim())) {
        session.saveLogin(username, password);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent log = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(log);
        handler.close();
        finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
```

`context` is `null`.

You should init this value in the constructor.